# Spam Traffic, DDOS Attack & Server Crashing

Tags: spam, network-traffic, traffic-filtering

I am running phpfox application in my server under my main domain name fetlock.com and I am getting large amount of spam and also suffering from DDOS attacks from multiple IP addresses. My server hardly stands for 20 hours and Apache stops responding after that, I manually need to reboot the server in order to make the server working again.

I initially expected that whether my IP address of PhpFox application is prone to DDOS attack and for testing purpose I changed the domain to testfetlock.tk and after changing domain I noticed there is no spam at all and server is stable for more than a week.

So, I understood that the domain fetlock.com is being under DDOS attack and I am receiving too much junk traffic, unwanted signups, etc.

Apart from using Application Level Spam filtering tools and plugins is there any way to prevent Server Level Spam? As the spam level seems too much and Server is crashing, is there any way to prevent this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it does fine for a few hours and then gradually gets slower, it could be a symptom of either a memory leak or runaway processes/threads. Try collecting information about resource usage over time, including memory, CPU, and network sockets.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should sniff some packet or analyze some log to find out the characteristics of the attack request. After that you can use mod_security to prevent it.
If you can build a reverse proxy by using nginx + apache, you can try out module Roboo to migrate the bot (if the bot not implemented to prcess JS or flask)
Link: https://github.com/yuri-gushin/Roboo

If you can, please sniff some packet and i think i will help you. Or you can analyze you access log and look at some information as:
- Is referer valid?
- Are User-Agent identical?
- Are User-Agent has some special point?
- Are they from the same country?
- How about their Request URL?
...

p/s: Nginx's limit_req module (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html) sometime usable.